# X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set debug issue even if X11Forwarding is set to yes on Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11

I am having this problem.

Debug message shows this:

```
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set 
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-41-generic x86_64)
```

`echo $DISPLAY` on my server returns `:1`

In my sshd_config I have:

```
X11Forwarding yes 
X11UseLocalHost no
```

For some reason it failed to work.

GPU details:NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
```

This error is about the local system--the one you ran `ssh` on. It's not about the remote system. It means that X11 forwarding was requested for the SSH session, but the DISPLAY variable isn't set for the `ssh` process. `ssh` needs the DISPLAY variable to be set so it knows where to forward X sessions to.

You could get this error by running `ssh` on a Windows or MacOS system, because neither of those use X for their GUI. You could also get this on a Linux/Unix system if you were running `ssh` from a text console instead of a GUI terminal window. If you're getting this error while running ssh from the GUI on a unix-like system, you should investigate why DISPLAY isn't set.

Comment: I tried Putty instead of OpenSSH provided by Windows and it worked. I am using Vcxsrv to display the GUI. Does this mean OpenSSH on Windoes does not support X11? or there's an additional configuration to be done?

Comment: @ArjeusGuevarra You should consider asking questions about windows on [su].